# PyTorch: What is numpy.linalg.multi_dot() equivalent in PyTorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to perform matrix multiplication of multiple matrices in PyTorch and was wondering what is the equivalent of `numpy.linalg.multi_dot()` in PyTorch?

If there isn't one, what is the next best way (in terms of speed and memory) I can do this in PyTorch?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import torch

A = np.random.rand(3, 3)
B = np.random.rand(3, 3)
C = np.random.rand(3, 3)

results = np.linalg.multi_dot(A, B, C)

A_tsr = torch.tensor(A)
B_tsr = torch.tensor(B)
C_tsr = torch.tensor(C)

# What is the PyTorch equivalent of np.linalg.multi_dot()?
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What's the timing for `multidot` compared to `A@B@C`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~~Looks like one can send tensors into multi_dot~~

Looks like the numpy implementation casts everything into numpy arrays. If your tensors are on the cpu and detached this should work. Otherwise, the conversion to numpy would fail.

So in general - likely there isn't an alternative. I think your best shot is to take the `multi_dot` implementation, e.g. [from here for numpy v1.19.0](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L2621-L2739) and adjust it to handle tensors / skip the cast to numpy. Given the similar interface and the code simplicity I think that this should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: I need to run the code in GPU, so I don't think I can use any numpy functions in GPU right?

Comment: Yep - just tried again with tensors on the gpu and it didn't work (updated the answer)..

Comment: Thanks! I guess I have to do the multiplication individually, like this: `torch.matmul(torch.matmul(A_tsr, B_tsr), C_tsr)`

Comment: Yep, which would not automatically choose the optimal order (I guess for three matrices shouldn't be a pain to do it manually if needed).

Comment: Ok, many thanks for this @Yuri Feldman. When I have time, I will put this on my list of to-do's as a mini project to contribute to PyTorch :)

Comment: `multidot` is only useful if the arrays differ in shape, and one order of evaluation is faster.

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch has the same interface: [torch.linalg.multi_dot](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.linalg.multi_dot.html)

You can use it like:

```
from torch.linalg import multi_dot

multi_dot([torch.tensor([1, 2]), torch.tensor([2, 3])])
multi_dot([torch.tensor([[1, 2]]), torch.tensor([2, 3])])
multi_dot([torch.tensor([[1, 2]]), torch.tensor([[2], [3]])])

A = torch.arange(2 * 3).view(2, 3)
B = torch.arange(3 * 2).view(3, 2)
C = torch.arange(2 * 2).view(2, 2)
result = multi_dot((A, B, C))
print(result)
```